# Firedac: GetFieldNames sem aspas

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

Estou recuperando os campos de tabelas *Firebird* e *Mysql* pelo *Firedac* Connection através da linha de comando `GetFieldNames`, entretanto alguns campos da lista são retornados com aspas.

Já tentei inserir nos parâmetros a diretiva `MetaDefCatalog=MySql` e não resolveu nada.

Abaixo está o código que utilizo para buscar a lista de campos de uma tabela:

```
Lista:=TStringList.Create;
FDConnection.GetFieldNames('','',Tabela,'',Lista);
if Lista.IndexOf('Campo') > 0 then
   //comandos para criar campo na tabela
```

O problema é que quando o campo é preenchido com aspas pelo *Firedac* (`DBExpress` não fazia isso) a cláusula `if` pede para criar o campo que já existe e gera um erro.

Como faço para resolver isso?

Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Os campos são retornados com Aspas devido a normalização do banco de dados.
Aqui uma abordagem pouco diferente: [Documentação.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/FireDAC.GetFieldNames_Sample)

> AList is a TStrings descendant that receives the field names. Any
>   existing strings are deleted from the list before GetFieldNames adds
>   the names of all the fields in ATableName.
>
> The field names are normalized--enclosed in quotation marks, if that
>   is required--otherwise converted to default dictionary case.

Existe varias funções que remove os caracteres indesejados, esta pode te ajudar, após obter os nomes e antes de inserir na lista, passe o resultado pela função:

```
function RemoveEspeciais(Texto: Ttring): Ttring; stdcall;
{Função que serve para nao aceitar caracteres especiais tipo !@#$%^&*()}
const
  NaoChar = '~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=|\<>,.?/æ';
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Length(Texto) do
    if Pos(Texto[i], NaoChar) <> 0 then
    else
    Result := Result + Texto[i];
end;
```

Caso não consiga adicionar a Aspa simples, adicione na constante da função o #39 que equivale a mesma!

**EDIT**

Mudando a abordagem, agora sabendo que o projeto é grande!

Declare nas uses de seu projeto: `FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait`

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.btnTesteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vNomeCampos : TStringList;
begin
  vNomeCampos := TStringList.Create;
  FDConnection.GetFieldNames('','','nome_tabela','',vNomeCampos);//nome_tabela entre Aspas!
  ShowMessage(vNomeCampos.Text);
end;
```

Comment: Júnior, obrigado por sua resposta. Mas o que eu espero é uma forma de normalizar o problema no FDConnection, porque eu tenho um arquivo imenso de atualização de versão que utiliza esta mesma função FDConnection.GetFieldNames para descobrir se o campo não existe cria-lo na tabela.

Comment: @prmas, Segue alteração na resposta, detalhe, a Versão de teste aqui é Tool = RAD Studio XE7
FireDAC = 11.0.1 (Build 73709)

Answer (score 1):

cara tenho um sistema de migração de dados desenvolvido e utilizo o getfildName para pegar os campos de uma determinada tambela da seguinte forma.

```
 fdconnection.GetFieldNames(NomeDoBanco,'',Tabela,'',StringList);
```

E pelo que ja utilizei do sistema ele nunca pegou ou o FireDac colocou aspas.
mas tente realizar o seguinte teste
o indexof pelo que pesquisei serve para sabermos qual índice que corresponde a string e ele retorna um valor do tipo int. Porem a string list começa em 0 e vai ate o final, talvez o seu campo esteja na posição 0, e vc esta validando se o mesmo é maior que 0.
Se for isso coloque um campo xyz para ver o retorno, acho que vai ser -1.

espero ter ajudado